# Export user list with Group and Team permissions from VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to export users from Azure DevOps with mapping to their permissions to specific Teams and Projects. The only option in the Azure DevOps is to export user list. But the associated Team and project access don't come along in that export.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am trying to do something similar. I want to start with a repo, release branch, etc., and get a list of users, groups, and their permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. But my user list was small so it was not hard to do it manually.

Comment: Yeah, our list things to check is getting very large...

Comment: I found this [deprecated project](https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Extracting-effective-permissions-from-TFS) that you might be able to make work, but I need to start with repos, release branches, etc., so a project that starts with users isn't that useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way to export associated Team and Projects for users. You can either search the user and choose **Member of** to see which security groups the user belongs to:

[image]

Or use [User Entitlements - Get User Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) api to get all use IDs and then use [User Entitlements - Get User Entitlement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) api get each user's entitlement, and you'll see projectEntitlements there.

Comment: Thanks!!! I am grappling with this issue and couldn't find a way to create the mapping.

Comment: Clarification question. I couldn't find the module in AzureDevops based on the screenshot you posted above, is that from the old VSTS? Or from Azure DevOps?

Comment: Alright, got it. Need to go to Organization Settings--> Security/Permissions--> Select Users.